# Ajax URL broken

Tags: html, ajax, path

I have an javascript setinterval which runs every 2 minutes to get latest feeds. However, this only work on the index page. The script is in a js file which I included in the main layout page of the site. What could be the cause? I know it has to do with the path, because when I check on Net tab in Firebug, the path is wrong. However, the file is included in the main layout, and every page has it(the layout).

Dont know if it will help, but my script is:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(myfx, my_time);
   }
   myfx(){ 
      ajax({ url: "mypage", ..)};

   }
```

I think the path is relative to the 'folder' that the user is currently in on the site,.. which is what is causing problems. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your URL is relative, which means the target that you're querying changes as you change pages. I.e. if you're at http://website.com/ then mypage is http://website.com/mypage, but if you're at http://website.com/help/details then mypage is at http://website.com/help/mypage, which probably doesn't exist.

The fix is to make your url absolute (start it with '/', e.g. /mypage) so that it always points to the same location.